# SQL запросы в Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi-7, ado

Это код программы для добавления полей в таблицу, но он добавляет поле только после перезапуска программы, что сделать, чтоб поле добавлялось сразу?

```
Table1.Active:=False;
Query2.Close;
Query2.Sql.Clear;
Query2.Sql.Add('alter table '+Edit4.Text+' add '+Edit2.Text+'char(20)');
Query2.execSQL;
DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
Table1.Active:=False;
end;
```

Comment: @vaska, код добавляет поле сразу. Пожалуйста, опишите свою проблему подробнее. В каком месте и в какой момент времени вы ожидаете увидеть изменения, и что вы для этого делаете (переоткрываете запрос, пересоздаете таблицу и т.д.).

Answer (score 1):

Если вы вручную не добавляли поля в Table1 (двойнок клик на компоненте -  - add all fields), тогда возможно будет работать даже такой вариант.

```
Query2.Sql.Text := 'alter table '+Edit4.Text+' add '+Edit2.Text+'char(20)';
Query2.execSQL;

Table1.Refresh;
```

или

```
Table1.Refresh;
DBGrid1.Columns.Clear;
DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
```

PS: Можно еще использовать EnableControl/DisableControl - не будет мерцать приложение при перестроении данные. И это все должно выполняться в блоке try-finally.

Answer (score 0):

В предпоследней строчке

```
Table1.Active := True;
```

Не?